# How to capture variable in Script Block?

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to return variable ($logstring) from the ScriptCommand to feed into the LogWriter function?

```
$ScriptCommand = "`$Cert  = Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine\My | where {`$_.thumbprint -eq `"$TP`"}
if(`$Cert.FriendlyName -eq `"$FriendlyName`")
{
`$logString = `"Friendly Name already $FriendlyName on $Node.`"
}
else 
{
`$Cert.FriendlyName = `"$FriendlyName`"
}"
$CommandScriptBlock = [Scriptblock]::Create($ScriptCommand)
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Node -ScriptBlock $CommandScriptBlock

LogWriter -LogFile $Lfile -LogString $logString
```

Comment: Sure. Just remove `$logString =`.

Comment: Just a tip here... You can do your scriptblock using brackets instead of using a string `$CommandScriptBlock = { $cert = Get-ChildItem ... }` That way you don't need the backticks escaping everywhere and your IDE will see errors (since you work with code rather than a string) and auto-format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To build on the helpful comments: It sounds like you want two things:

- Execute a script block remotely that contains references to *local* variable values.

  - For that, define your script block - as usual - as *script-block literal*, i.e. enclosed in `{ ... }`; as [Sage Pourpre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/934946/sage-pourpre) notes, not only does this avoid quoting and escaping headaches, it allows your IDE to syntax-highlight and -check the code inside the block.
  - The simplest way to incorporate *local* variable values is via the `$using:` scope; e.g., `$using:FriendlyName` - see the relevant section of the conceptual [about_Scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-7.2#the-using-scope-modifier) help topic. This obviates the need to construct the text of your script block *as a string* that relies on *string interpolation*.
- Output a value from that script block and capture it in local variable `$logString`. (You categorically cannot set a *local* variable directly in a *remotely* executing script block).

To put it all together:

```sh
# Define the script block for remote execution as a literal.
# Reference local variable values via $using:
$commandScriptBlock = {

  $Cert  = Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine\My | 
             Where-Object { $_.thumbprint -eq $using:TP }
  if ($Cert.FriendlyName -eq $using:FriendlyName) {
    # Output text for logging.
    "Friendly Name already $using:FriendlyName on $using:Node."
  }
  else {
    # Note: No text is being output here.
    $Cert.FriendlyName = $using:FriendlyName
  } 

}

# Invoke the script block remotely and capture its output in $logString
$logString = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Node -ScriptBlock $commandScriptBlock

LogWriter -LogFile $Lfile -LogString $logString
```